# Should I use properties to parse console input?

Tags: c#, parsing, properties

I'm building a console app and I have a parsing function, two actually, that cleans the user input to after insert in a database. But after I parse the values I save them in a object and then I use a method of the object to save the data in the database.

Here is what I have:

```
static int TryParse(string lable, string field)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string rgx; 
            string warning;
            switch (field)
            {
                case "phone":
                    rgx = @"\b\d{4}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}\b";
                    warning = @"Por favor insira apenas números (máximo de 8 dígitos) ou no seguinte formato: XXXX-XX-XX.";
                    break;
                case "postal":
                    rgx = @"\b\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}\b";
                    warning = @"Por favor insira apenas números (máximo de 8 dígitos) ou no seguinte formato: XX-XXX-XXX.";
                    break;
                case "area":
                    rgx = @"\b\d{2}\b";
                    warning = @"Por favor insira apenas números (máximo de 2 dígitos). Código de área sem o 0.";
                    break;
                default:
                    rgx = @"\d+";
                    warning = @"Por favor insira apenas números.";
                    break;
            }
            Regex regex = new Regex(rgx);

            while (!regex.IsMatch(str))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(warning);
                Console.Write(lable);
                str = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(str.Replace("-",""));
        }//End of TryParse();
```

The other function just returns a string cause its for an e-mail field.

My class is:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string skype;
        public string main_email;
        public string company;

        public int main_phone;
        public int main_phone_area;
        public int postal_code;
```

And has a save method, the whole CRUD, constructors, etc...

So, should I instead of parsing the way I do, in the Program (main), parse using the objects properties?

EDIT1:

The console read/writes are in the main already.

Comment: I would move the console reads/writes to the Main and have the parse take more parameters to compensate. This will allow more reusabalility if your input methods changes (ex. adding a web interface or actual gui).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion would be to do it in the Business Object. The reason being that you can reuse the validation later on another project.

You can also look into [ValidationAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) which gives you a nice and clean way to validate business objects.

You can also look into [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) as another powerful alternative.